# How to populate content dynamically in PHP with the click of a button (possibly using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php

I would like a user to click a button with a specific ID, which would then dynamically add that ID to multiple parts of a PHP document, displayed beneath the button.

I'm loading information server-side as well, so I have to use PHP for some of the other contents in the file.

```html
<a href="" data-product_id="1503">Button</a>
```

```
<?php
// additional necessary php
?>
<div id="insert data-product_id here">
<p name="insert data-product_id here"></p>
</div>
```

I've attempted to use an onClick with the `element.getAttribute('data-product_id');` but I can't figure out how to then implement that into the PHP file.

If there's a way to do this entirely in PHP that'd be ideal, I'm just stuck on how to accomplish it.

Comment: Are you willing to consider a solution in JavaScript that would not require reloading the entire page?

Comment: @Justin definitely!

Comment: this is Ajax theme

Comment: Use Ajax. Upon success of the execution of your PHP code, update the DOM Ids for the elements that you want.